# Create new dataframe from an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with say 6 columns. 3 of the columns are of length 5.  Two of the columns are of length 2 and the last column is of length 8.  The columns are randomly positioned in the dataframe.  I would like to create 3 new dataframes.  The first dataframe should only contain all the columns whose length is 5.  The second dataframe should only contain the columns with length 2 and the third data frame should only contain column of length 8.  How do I do this?

Comment: Pls show some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: what are other values for shorter columns? `NaN` ?

Comment: Yes the other empty values are NaNs

Comment: Heres my sample code:
test_data = {'Col_1':[1,4,65,78,54],
        'Col_5':[45,11],
       'Col_2':[2,3,56,34,23],
        'Col_6':[34,1,2,3,55,67,89,78],
       'Col_3':[34,55,15,33,78],
       'Col_4':[34,44],   
       }
test_df = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in test_data.items() })

Comment: You can count the number of NANs in one column with df['ColumnName'].isna().sum()

Comment: Is there any other `NaN` values among above end `NaN` values? I mean for example for columns with length 5, is there NaN values wmong these five values?

Comment: No.  The NaN values are only at the end of the column of data as a padding

Comment: My first dataframe should contain only Col_1, Col_2 and Col_3, my second dataframe should only contain Col_4 and Col_5 and my last dataframe should only contain Col_6

Comment: What do you mean by `length` here in:- `The first dataframe should only contain all the columns whose length is 5.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do this:

```
df_length_5 = df[[col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].dropna()) == 5]].dropna()
df_length_2 = df[[col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].dropna()) == 2]].dropna()
df_length_8 = df[[col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].dropna()) == 8]].dropna()
```

Comment: Throws an invalid syntax next to for

Comment: What is the message for that invalid syntax?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-178-debef1ece9f3>", line 1
    df_length_5 = df[col for col in df if(len(df[col].dropna()) == 5)]
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know how it works.

Comment: This works well ashkang - I used your original version and added the brackets at the end and an additional .dropna()

df_length_5 = test_df[[x for x in test_df if(len(test_df[x].dropna()) == 5)]].dropna()
df_length_3 = test_df[[x for x in test_df if(len(test_df[x].dropna()) == 2)]].dropna()
df_length_8 = test_df[[x for x in test_df if(len(test_df[x].dropna()) == 8)]].dropna()

Comment: I will validate your 2nd version in a few minutes ashkang...Thanks so much for the brilliant work man...